# Why JWrapper JRE does not include javaws

Tags: java, java-web-start, jwrapper

Why JWrapper JRE does not include javaws file, even when I using tag NoStripJREs=true.

How to run jnlp file using JWrapper JRE, like run another application via jnlp in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the NoStripJRE tag is specified correctly you'll see this during the build output:

[Config] Will not strip JRE (leaving optional files)

However if you have already built the JRE then JWrapper won't build it again unless you delete the output JRE archives in your build folder.  If you delete those then it will rebuild the JRE archives (this will take minutes) and it should leave the JRE as is.